# Find a string within another string, search backwards

Tags: c#, string

```
int d;
d = some_string.IndexOf("something",1000);
```

I want `indexOf` to search `some_string`, starting at position 1000 and searching backwards. is this possible?

Comment: could you explain a bit?

Comment: Do you want to search after 1000 or before 1000?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

How about [LastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof%28VS.80%29.aspx)?

From MSDN:

> Reports the index position of the last
>   occurrence of a specified String
>   within this instance...The search **begins** at the *startIndex*
>   character position of this instance
>   and **proceeds backwards** towards the
>   beginning until either *value* is found
>   or the first character position has
>   been examined.

```
int index = some_string.LastIndexOf("something", 1000);
```

Comment: `some_string.LastIndexOf("something", 0, 1000)` to be precise. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0z3tk9t%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: @Zach It seems to me that he wants to search the range of [0, 1000]

Comment: @Justin: The starting index is the index from which to proceed *backward*, which makes it confusing and unintuitive compared to `IndexOf`.  So actually it would be `some_string.LastIndexOf("something", 1000, 1000)`. I've been bitten by this one before.